# Require logging in to view page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have 2 pages:

login.aspx <Public

user.aspx <Should be locked behind a login

I have been trying to get this to work but I have not idea where to go from where I am now. Google mainly shows C# instead of vb.net.
I created a login page which works and continues to the next page.

However..

I can also type in the next page URL and I would not need to login.
How can I make it so the 2nd page tells me you need to be logged in to view this page.

What I have so far is:

login.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="login.aspx.vb" Inherits="web.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            height: 172px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="auto-style1">
            Loginpage<br />
            <br />
            user:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            password:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load



    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        con.ConnectionString = "myconstring"

        Dim objcon As SqlConnection = Nothing
        Dim objcmd As SqlCommand = Nothing

        objcon = New SqlConnection("myconstring")
        objcon.Open()

        Dim stmt As String = "select * from login where Username = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND Password = '" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
        objcmd = New SqlCommand(stmt, objcon)

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = objcmd.ExecuteReader
        If reader.Read Then
            Response.Redirect("user\user.aspx")
        Else
            Label1.Visible = True
            Label1.Text = "Login onjuist"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: "Google mainly shows C# instead of VB" - get used to it. C# is a far more popular language. If you want to be an effective VB developer, you're most likely going to have to learn C# (or at least read it) because most .NET examples will be in C#. It's really not that difficult to read C# if you know VB - the syntax isn't so different that you can't understand it.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code behind of your users page you can check if the user is authenticated. If they are not authenticated, you can redirect them to a page that informs them they must be logged in to access the page they were trying to visit. The code below just redirects to the login page.

```
        If HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = False Then
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx")
        End If
```

Another option is you can define a location section in your web.config. The following code denies access to users.aspx, for users that are not authenticated.

```
  <location path="users.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```